# Function to return count of duplicate numbers in sorted array

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, divide-and-conquer

I want to return the number of duplicate values in a sorted array.

For example: a = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4 }, fratelli(n) should return 2. (They are 1, 1 and 4, 4)

I attempted to use a recursive approach, but it doesn't work. It Always give me 4.

I'm asking if someone please could help me understand better this methods of programming. Thanks a lot!

The function:

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;

    int fratelli(int a[], int l, int r)
    {
        if (l == r) return 0;
        else 
        {
            int c = (l+r) / 2;
            int n = fratelli(a, l, c) + fratelli(a, c+1, r);
            if (a[l] == a[l+1]) n++;
            return n;
        }

    }


    int main()
    {
        const int _N = 11;
        int array[_N] = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 11, 12 };

        cout << "\n" << fratelli(array, 0, _N-1);


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: if you have a = {1,1,1} should it return 2 or 1?

Comment: Don't use `_N` for a variable name. Names beginning with an underscore and an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Are You sure You want to use recursion? If I have understood it right, recursion makes the problem more difficult.

Comment: @gkovacs90 Yes because it is an exercise :) There isn't specified about that behaviour... Let's consider the simpler way, so it should return 2 (considering Infested comment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error on this line:

```
if (a[l] == a[l+1]) n++;
```

The check should be at index `c` not at `l`. Apart from this your code seems alright to me.

Comment: how will it change it? so instead of checking from left, itll check from right.

Comment: @Infested no this checks if the two elements at the split are equal so that OP does not miss a pair split over the two partitions.

Comment: It works! Can you please give me a little explaination of that?

Comment: even better, might end up over-counting

Comment: @tuttoscorre The number of adjacent equal numbers in a list is equal to (number in right partition) + (number in left partition) + (1 if the two center elements are the same).

Comment: which ill ask again: if you have a = {1,1,1} should it return 2 or 1?

Comment: @Infested as I understand the statement it should be 2

Comment: @Infested I asnwered on the up comment, 2

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev Thanks a lot. I didn't understand why I should use center index instead of left index...